# Doubt about integration substitution

Tags: integration, limits, analysis, improper-integrals

Suppose I have to evaluate
$$\int_0^\infty f(x) \text{d}x$$
And I would like to use the substitution $x^2=\frac{t}{1-t}$.

Now I must find the new integration interval in the variable $t$, I suppose I need to do a thing like this: if $x=0$ we have $0=\frac{t}{1-t}$ and so $t=0$, if $x\to\infty$ then $\frac{t}{1-t} \to \infty$ and this is true when $t \to 1^-$.

My questions are:

(1) is this correct? Is there a rigorous way to to this?

(2) I know that when I make substitutions in integrals they must be bijective, but I'm confused if I must verify that $x^2$ is bijective or $\frac{t}{1-t}$; in this case they are both increasing, so maybe it can help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x^{2}=\frac t {1-t}$ iff $t=\frac {x^{2}} {1+x^{2}}$. Using this it is easy to check that $x \to t$ is indeed bijective from $(0,\infty)$ on,to $(0,1)$. So the substitution is legitimate the integral transforms to an integral from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, some questions: is $x \mapsto t$ bijective because $\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}$ is strictly increasing in $(0,\infty)$? Is $(0,\infty)$ mapped in $(0,1)$ through $t=\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}=g(x)$ because, with a study of function, we study $g$ only for $x>0$ (because of the integration interval) and we notice that $g(x) \to 0$ for $x \to 0$ and $g(x) \to 1$ for $x \to \infty$ and we use the intermediate value theorem since $g$ is continuous? Why do we consider $(0,\infty)$ and not $[0,\infty)$? Thanks.